# "para cuando" vs "cuando"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

> **Para cuando** me di cuenta, ya era demasiado tarde.
>   **Cuando** me di cuenta, ya era demasiado tarde.

¿Existe alguna diferencia en el signficado de estas oraciones? ¿Es correcto el uso de "para cuando"?

Ambas me parecen correctas, mas no sé exactamente cual es la diferencia. Quizá la razon por la que "para cuando" me parece correcta es por la frase en ingles "by the time ..." pero no quiere decir que lo sea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambas son correctas, en sintaxis pertenecen al grupo de oraciones subordinadas adverbiales de tiempo.

Oración subordinada porque en ambas frases una oración depende de la otra, no son independientes.

El 'cuando' en ambas determina el tiempo del verbo. Ni antes ni después, justo en ese momento.

> Para cuando me di cuenta...entonces era demasiado tarde.
>
> Cuando me di cuenta...entonces era demasiado tarde

Encontré este [documento](http://www.avempace.com/file_download/380/15-subordinadasadverbiales.pdf), copio una parte

> Las subordinadas temporales pueden tener distintas estructuras:
>
> - Introducidas por el adverbio relativo cuando (sin antecedente expreso): Nos
>     (CCT) vemos cuando acabe el curso (CCT-PS Adv)
> - Introducidas por otros nexos equivalentes que expresan tiempo: mientras, antes (de) que, después (de) que, en cuanto, apenas, al tiempo que, en tanto (que), no bien, a medida que, según, desde que…
>     Ejs.: En cuanto termines, (CPrep-PS Adv T) ven aquí. Mientras esperamos, (CCT-PS Adv) tomemos una caña….

'Para' actúa como nexo en la primera.

> Para cuando vengas tú (CPrep-CCT) ya me habré ido yo.

Para cuando no es incorrecta como demuestra en el libro *La puntuación al alcance de todos escrito por Myriam Bustos Arrati*

> Las oraciones subordinadas adverbiales de tiempo van encabezadas generalmente por alguno de los siguientes elementos:
>
> Cuando(a veces, precedido de preposición: para cuando)

Para el primer ejemplo se podría decir *Para cuando quise darme cuenta, ya era demasiado tarde*

Answer (score 0):

At least in Argentina, "para cuando" sounds more colloquial. I should try to avoid it in very formal documents. However, as it was mention before, both options are gramatically correct.